# get value distribution via SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, histogram

In a MySQL database there's a table with a single numeric `value` column. I want to plot the distribution of these values as a bar chart. The width of each bar in the chart should be uniform and the height of each bar should reflect the number of entries in this range.

For example, if the range of values is from `-10..90` and the number of ranges (bars) is 10, then the first bar in the chart should show the number of entries in the range `-10..0` and the last should show the number of entries in the range `80..90`.

Is there a better way to calculate the bar chart data than the following:

1. Get min and max with `select min(value), max(value) from mytable`
2. Calculate the upper and lower bounds of each range (in application code)
3. Get the number of values in each range with `select count(*) from mytable where value between X and Y`

A problem with this simplistic approach is that a separate query will need to be issued to find the number of values in each range, is it possible to make this more efficient, e.g. by building up the query dynamically and using a `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  19 |
|  2 |  10 |
|  3 |   6 |
|  4 |  29 |
|  6 |  27 |
|  7 |  20 |
|  8 |  11 |
|  9 |  12 |
| 13 |  16 |
| 14 |  38 |
| 15 |   8 |
| 16 |  22 |
| 17 |  23 |
| 18 |  16 |
| 19 |  20 |
| 20 |  18 |
| 28 |  18 |
| 29 |   7 |
| 30 |  10 |
| 31 |  34 |
| 32 |  11 |
| 33 |  17 |
| 34 |  15 |
| 35 |  12 |
| 36 |  19 |
| 37 |  15 |
| 38 |  18 |
| 39 |  24 |
| 40 |  10 |
| 41 |  19 |
| 42 |  25 |
| 43 |  22 |
| 59 |  27 |
| 60 |  14 |
| 61 |  17 |
| 62 |  25 |
| 63 |  28 |
| 64 |  20 |
| 65 |  10 |
| 66 |  18 |
| 67 |  22 |
| 68 |  12 |
| 69 |  18 |
| 70 |  31 |
| 71 |  22 |
| 72 |  23 |
| 73 |  20 |
| 74 |  12 |
| 75 |  10 |
| 76 |   9 |
| 77 |  21 |
| 78 |  18 |
| 79 |  14 |
| 80 |  17 |
| 81 |   7 |
| 82 |  21 |
| 83 |  11 |
| 84 |  16 |
| 85 |  19 |
| 86 |  30 |
| 87 |  11 |
| 88 |  18 |
| 89 |  26 |
| 90 |  16 |
+----+-----+

SELECT CEILING(((1+val-(SELECT MIN(val) FROM my_table)))/ROUND((SELECT MAX(val)-MIN(val) FROM my_table)/8)) x
     , COUNT(*)
     , GROUP_CONCAT(LPAD(val,2,0) ORDER BY val) n
  FROM my_table
 GROUP
    BY CEILING(((1+val-(SELECT MIN(val) FROM my_table)))/ROUND((SELECT MAX(val)-MIN(val) FROM my_table)/8)); 
+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| x    | COUNT(*) | n                                                  |
+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 |        5 | 06,07,07,08,09                                     |
|    2 |       13 | 10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12             |
|    3 |       11 | 14,14,15,15,16,16,16,16,17,17,17                   |
|    4 |       17 | 18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,21,21 |
|    5 |        9 | 22,22,22,22,23,23,24,25,25                         |
|    6 |        5 | 26,27,27,28,29                                     |
|    7 |        2 | 30,31                                              |
|    8 |        1 | 34                                                 |
|    9 |        1 | 38                                                 |
+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't think this helps me. In your example, the groups are the values themselves, this is not the case for me. If you think I'm mistaken, could you rework this example such that `dt` is a decimal column, and the groups consist of values in ranges of equal widths?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN (max(numb) - min(numb) BETWEEN xx AND yy THEN zz
WHEN (max(numb) - min(numb) BETWEEN zz AND aa THEN cc
```

will handle your sizing of your bar chart and a GROUP BY in another query will give you the values in each distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the ranges are unknown and you must determine each dynamically. Find the min and max values as you have done. Using a cursor, calculate the upper and lower bounds for each range and save the results to a temporary table containing fields such as *rangeLabel, lowerBound, upperBound*. Select the temp table and look up the counts with a subquery:

```
SELECT rangeLabel, (SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable 
    WHERE value BETWEEN temp.lowerBound AND temp.Upperbound) as myCount
FROM temp
```